# how can I fix shading artifacts on my mesh?

Tags: mesh

So I crated the following mesh and after applying subdivision it looks weird.

I tried:
-merging vertices by distance
-Recalculate normals

Also I added loops to make the corners sharper but the loop does not go all the way around, it is skipping the triangle on the shoulder and the box on the bottom.
How can I fix it ?

[image]

[image]

Here is the file
[image]

Comment: It's due to n-gons. Just fix them with the knife tool, if you manage to make all your faces to quads, those should disappear

Comment: If you don't know how to do that, you can upload your file and I'll help you.

Comment: I tried adding extensions to the missing loop line it seems it made it worst. Also, I understand I need to convert the faces into 4 corner but not sure how to do that with a triangle.  If you do not mind showing it to me I would appreciate it. Uploading the file

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=LoeS1JD2" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/LoeS1JD2/)

Answer (score 2):

It's because of the topology of your mesh (the faces, edges and vertices).  Blender (and any other 3D software for that matter) does not really like n-gons, which are faces with more than 4 sides to it.  You can see that some places in your mesh are missing the edge that the previous faces have?

[image: edges missing!]

That sometimes happen to me when I use the 'merge by distance' with too much of a distance.  To fix this you have to create edges in the n-gons to turn them into quads, you can join the vertices together (ctrl + j) or use the knife tool.

Getting great topology is fundamental for 3D artists, and investing time in learning will pay off long term, so I'll leave you some reading about topology, and recommend you learn how to use the `join` or `Ctrl + j` and Select Faces by Sides to find which faces are n-gons by selecting greater than 4 sides!  (https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/meshes/selecting/all_by_trait.html) also check the knife tool: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/3.1/modeling/meshes/tools/knife.html

Some reading from Polygon:

http://wiki.polycount.com/wiki/Topology

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to consider when checking the topology of your mesh. We've already pointed out the problems with normals and non-quad faces.

In the blend files you provided, I see that you already made the faces on the bottom-right of the mesh to quad but there are still a weird shading there :

[image]

The reason for this is **duplicate geometry** (edges and/or faces):

[image]

Entering face select mode makes the problem obvious, you probably created those face while attempting to fix the n-gon problem.

You can just delete those three faces and refill it :

[image]

With this edge selected press <kbd>F</kbd> and a face will be filled automatically. Same with those ones :

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

After that, the bottom part of the mesh should be clean :

[image]

There is another one here :

[image]

You can clean it the same way as the others.

For the upper part, just use the knife tool (pressing <kbd>K</kbd>) :

[image]

After that, you'll see that it's already better :

[image]
[image]

But you still have a triangle. Depending on what you want to do, you may want to fix it, you can't do this by either creating a loopcut to have an extra vertex or by merging the two edge loops to collapse the triangle, the two should be fairly easy to do.

Anyway, I hope this helped you as the question was how to get rid of the artifacts :

[image]

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks so much!!